# Chrome - Finding which other extensions are using a particular permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing an extension that requires proxy permissions. For that, I also need to block out or atleast detect any other extension currently active with proxy permissions. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's heavy-handed, but you can use [Management API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management).

```
chrome.management.getAll(function(details){
  var proxyIds = [];
  for(var i in details){
    if(details[i].permissions.filter(function(el){return el == "proxy"}).length > 0){
      proxyIds.push(details[i].id);
    }
  }
  /* use proxyIds */
});
```